# Passage from Sri-Bhashya question

Tags: ramanujacharya

The following is said in the English translation by M Rang Acharya, MB Varadaraja Aiyanger

> The seat of His three powers, viz. the higher power which is this (above mentioned) unembodied (form of the self), the (other) lower power which is the (self's) embodied form called the kshetrajna, and ignorance (or avidyd) which is of the nature of karma and is known as the third power and which forms the cause of leading the self, Which is of the nature of the higher power, to assume the condition of the kshetrajna —(this embodied form of the Brahman) which is peculiar to the Divine Lord.

**Is this to say that the Divine Lord is the only one to possess karma, embodied and unembodied natures?** Where and how is this established? What is the implication of his statement as it relates to suitability of objects for dharana as it relates to the unembodied form of the Brahman? How is unembodied different from or the same as unmanifest?

Comment: you need to clarify which verse is being asked about.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure how to answer your question, Swami Vishwananda. The words I referenced were from page 131 of the book I was reading.  Several passages are cited, but no-one quote in particular is my reference; rather, mine is a reference to the "cause" of the self being led and how it seems to relate to me, and what propels me forward. I'm curious to understand if some element of what is written refers to the Brahman within thine own self being realized through the Divine Lord? Thank you for taking the time to reply to me. I apologize it has taken me this long to reply. - Dharma Sadhak